# Filter function in SML

Tags: sml

I use this function to filter a list of integers. I'm beggining in SML and I don't know where is the error.

```
fun filter f = fn [] => []
| fn (x::xs) => if f(x)
then x::(filter f xs) else (filter f xs)

fun g(x) = if x>5 then true else false

val listTest = filter g [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you receive any error? If yes, please, can you copy it here? Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitions with `fn` look like definitions with `fun`, but without the name and an arrow instead of `=`:

```
fn a0 => e0
 | a1 => e1
 | ...
```

This would be correct:

```
fun filter f = fn [] => []
                | (x::xs) => if f(x)
                             then x::(filter f xs) 
                             else (filter f xs)
```

but the common form is

```
fun filter _ [] = []
  | filter f (x::xs) = if f x
                       then x :: filter f xs
                       else filter f xs

fun g x = x > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You second `fn` is redundant, please remove it:

```
fun filter f = fn [] => []
| (x::xs) => if f(x)
then x::(filter f xs) else (filter f xs)
```

Then it can compile happily:

```
- use "a.sml";
[opening a.sml]
val filter = fn : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
val g = fn : int -> bool
val listTest = [6,8,10] : int list
val it = () : unit
```

BTW, `fun g(x) = if x>5 then true else false` is not good style. `fun g x = x > 5` is better