# Switch on template argument: does gcc remove the switch?

Tags: c++, templates, switch-statement

Will (or can?) a switch statement based on a template argument be removed by the compiler?

See for example the following function in which the template argument `funcStep1` is used to select the appropriate function. Will this switch statement be removed as its argument is known at compile time? I tried to learn it from the assembly code (given below) but I have no experience in reading assembly yet so this is not really a feasible task for me.

This question became now relevant for me since the newly introduced `if constexpr` provides an alternative that is guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time.

```
template<int funcStep1>
double Mdp::expectedCost(int sdx0, int x0, int x1, int adx0, int adx1) const
{
  switch (funcStep1)
  {
    case 1:
    case 3:
      return expectedCost_exact(sdx0, x0, x1, adx0, adx1);

    case 2:
    case 4:
      return expectedCost_approx(sdx0, x0, x1, adx0, adx1);

    default:
      throw string("Unknown value (Mdp::expectedCost.cc)");
  }
}

// Define all the template types we need
template double Mdp::expectedCost<1>(int, int, int, int, int) const;
template double Mdp::expectedCost<2>(int, int, int, int, int) const;
template double Mdp::expectedCost<3>(int, int, int, int, int) const;
template double Mdp::expectedCost<4>(int, int, int, int, int) const;
```

Here you find the output of 'objdump -D' when the above function is compiled with gcc -O2 -ffunction-sections:

```
1expectedCost.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .group:

0000000000000000 <.group>:
   0:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
   2:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
   4:   08 00                   or     %al,(%rax)
   6:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
   8:   09 00                   or     %eax,(%rax)
    ...

Disassembly of section .group:

0000000000000000 <.group>:
   0:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
   2:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
   4:   0a 00                   or     (%rax),%al
   6:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
   8:   0b 00                   or     (%rax),%eax
    ...

Disassembly of section .group:

0000000000000000 <.group>:
   0:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
   2:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
   4:   0c 00                   or     $0x0,%al
   6:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
   8:   0d                      .byte 0xd
   9:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    ...

Disassembly of section .group:

0000000000000000 <.group>:
   0:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
   2:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
   4:   0e                      (bad)  
   5:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
   7:   00 0f                   add    %cl,(%rdi)
   9:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    ...

Disassembly of section .bss:

0000000000000000 <_ZStL8__ioinit>:
    ...

Disassembly of section .text._ZNK3Mdp12expectedCostILi1EEEdiiiii:

0000000000000000 <_ZNK3Mdp12expectedCostILi1EEEdiiiii>:
   0:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   5 <_ZNK3Mdp12expectedCostILi1EEEdiiiii+0x5>

Disassembly of section .text._ZNK3Mdp12expectedCostILi2EEEdiiiii:

0000000000000000 <_ZNK3Mdp12expectedCostILi2EEEdiiiii>:
   0:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   5 <_ZNK3Mdp12expectedCostILi2EEEdiiiii+0x5>

Disassembly of section .text._ZNK3Mdp12expectedCostILi3EEEdiiiii:

0000000000000000 <_ZNK3Mdp12expectedCostILi3EEEdiiiii>:
   0:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   5 <_ZNK3Mdp12expectedCostILi3EEEdiiiii+0x5>

Disassembly of section .text._ZNK3Mdp12expectedCostILi4EEEdiiiii:

0000000000000000 <_ZNK3Mdp12expectedCostILi4EEEdiiiii>:
   0:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   5 <_ZNK3Mdp12expectedCostILi4EEEdiiiii+0x5>

Disassembly of section .text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_expectedCost.cc:

0000000000000000 <_GLOBAL__sub_I_expectedCost.cc>:
   0:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 7 <_GLOBAL__sub_I_expectedCost.cc+0x7>
   7:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
   b:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  10 <_GLOBAL__sub_I_expectedCost.cc+0x10>
  10:   48 8b 3d 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 17 <_GLOBAL__sub_I_expectedCost.cc+0x17>
  17:   48 8d 15 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdx        # 1e <_GLOBAL__sub_I_expectedCost.cc+0x1e>
  1e:   48 8d 35 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rsi        # 25 <_GLOBAL__sub_I_expectedCost.cc+0x25>
  25:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  29:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   2e <_GLOBAL__sub_I_expectedCost.cc+0x2e>

Disassembly of section .init_array:

0000000000000000 <.init_array>:
    ...

Disassembly of section .comment:

0000000000000000 <.comment>:
   0:   00 47 43                add    %al,0x43(%rdi)
   3:   43 3a 20                rex.XB cmp (%r8),%spl
   6:   28 55 62                sub    %dl,0x62(%rbp)
   9:   75 6e                   jne    79 <_ZStL8__ioinit+0x79>
   b:   74 75                   je     82 <_ZStL8__ioinit+0x82>
   d:   20 37                   and    %dh,(%rdi)
   f:   2e 33 2e                xor    %cs:(%rsi),%ebp
  12:   30 2d 32 37 75 62       xor    %ch,0x62753732(%rip)        # 6275374a <_ZStL8__ioinit+0x6275374a>
  18:   75 6e                   jne    88 <_ZStL8__ioinit+0x88>
  1a:   74 75                   je     91 <_ZStL8__ioinit+0x91>
  1c:   31 7e 31                xor    %edi,0x31(%rsi)
  1f:   38 2e                   cmp    %ch,(%rsi)
  21:   30 34 29                xor    %dh,(%rcx,%rbp,1)
  24:   20 37                   and    %dh,(%rdi)
  26:   2e 33 2e                xor    %cs:(%rsi),%ebp
  29:   30 00                   xor    %al,(%rax)

Disassembly of section .eh_frame:

0000000000000000 <.eh_frame>:
   0:   14 00                   adc    $0x0,%al
   2:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
   4:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
   6:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
   8:   01 7a 52                add    %edi,0x52(%rdx)
   b:   00 01                   add    %al,(%rcx)
   d:   78 10                   js     1f <.eh_frame+0x1f>
   f:   01 1b                   add    %ebx,(%rbx)
  11:   0c 07                   or     $0x7,%al
  13:   08 90 01 00 00 10       or     %dl,0x10000001(%rax)
  19:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  1b:   00 1c 00                add    %bl,(%rax,%rax,1)
  1e:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  20:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  22:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  24:   05 00 00 00 00          add    $0x0,%eax
  29:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  2b:   00 10                   add    %dl,(%rax)
  2d:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  2f:   00 30                   add    %dh,(%rax)
  31:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  33:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  35:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  37:   00 05 00 00 00 00       add    %al,0x0(%rip)        # 3d <.eh_frame+0x3d>
  3d:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  3f:   00 10                   add    %dl,(%rax)
  41:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  43:   00 44 00 00             add    %al,0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  47:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  49:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4b:   00 05 00 00 00 00       add    %al,0x0(%rip)        # 51 <.eh_frame+0x51>
  51:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  53:   00 10                   add    %dl,(%rax)
  55:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  57:   00 58 00                add    %bl,0x0(%rax)
  5a:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  5c:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  5e:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  60:   05 00 00 00 00          add    $0x0,%eax
  65:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  67:   00 14 00                add    %dl,(%rax,%rax,1)
  6a:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  6c:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  6d:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  6f:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  71:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  73:   00 2e                   add    %ch,(%rsi)
  75:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  77:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  79:   4b 0e                   rex.WXB (bad) 
  7b:   10 5e 0e                adc    %bl,0xe(%rsi)
  7e:   08 00                   or     %al,(%rax)
```

Comment: I haven't looked into the assembly code, but without looking, I can tell you for sure that the compiler will optimize constants out.

Comment: You may also be interested in the [constexpr specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

Comment: It might not get optimized out if you compile with `-O0`, otherwise I would expect it to be optimized.

Comment: I would replace your `throw` by `static_assert(1 <= funcStep1 && funcStep1 <= 4);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is optimized. There are a few things that make reading assembly easier, such as demangling names (example: `_ZNK3Mdp12expectedCostILi1EEEdiiiii` is the mangled form of `double Mdp::expectedCost<1>(int, int, int, int, int) const`), stripping comments and text (and using Intel syntax):

```
double expectedCost<1>(int, int, int, int, int):           # @double expectedCost<1>(int, int, int, int, int)
        jmp     expectedCost_exact(int, int, int, int, int) # TAILCALL
double expectedCost<2>(int, int, int, int, int):           # @double expectedCost<2>(int, int, int, int, int)
        jmp     expectedCost_approx(int, int, int, int, int) # TAILCALL
double expectedCost<3>(int, int, int, int, int):           # @double expectedCost<3>(int, int, int, int, int)
        jmp     expectedCost_exact(int, int, int, int, int) # TAILCALL
double expectedCost<4>(int, int, int, int, int):           # @double expectedCost<4>(int, int, int, int, int)
        jmp     expectedCost_approx(int, int, int, int, int) # TAILCALL
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ZtoKFH

The above site simplifies this whole process for you.

In this case I didn't provide definitions for `expectedCost_approx` so the compiler just leaves a jump. But in any case, compilers are *definitely* smart enough to realize that each template function has a constant value in the switch.

Comment: That website is excellent, I already almost gave up hope of ever understanding assembly!

Comment: @Michiel it is indeed a very good website. And don't be intimidated by assembly. While writing good assembly is a whole different story, reading assembly a compiler wrote for you is by far not as hard as it may sound. In fact, it's actually quite simple, especially with the tooltips that tell you what each instruction does, just takes some time to get used to. It's a very important skill if you care about performance at all, which you probably do since you're using C++ ;)…

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is: Yes, any moderately useful compiler will [perform dead code elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination).

`if constexpr` is not so much about forcing compile time evaluation for reasons of performance. In terms of performance, there's not really going to be any difference between `if constexpr` and a normal `if` when the given expression is a compile-time constant because compilers will end up optimizing the unused branch away either way. What `if constexpr` enables is to have code in the inactive branch that must not be instantiated with the given template arguments (e.g., because it would be invalid in that particular case). For your switch above, the whole code will be instantiated for all cases. Only afterwards will the unused code be removed by the optimizer. `if constexpr` on the other hand, guarantees that the code in the unused branch will never be instantiated to begin with. See, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809853/if-vs-if-constexpr-inside-constexpr-function) for more on that…

Answer (score 1):

We don't have `switch constexpr`, and there are no guaranties of branch elimination for simple `switch`, even with `constexpr` value (as for regular `if` in fact), but I expect than compiler would remove them with proper optimization flag.

Notice also that your not-used branches would instantiate, if any, template methods/objects whereas `if constexpr` would not.

So if you want to have guaranty that only relevant code is there, or avoid unneeded instantiations, use `if constexpr`. Else use the one you find the clearer.